# why i can't add a simple background image in css/html?

Tags: html, css

i have tried adding an img tag with the same src and it works but i don't know why this is not working...

```
**html code**
 <html>
 <head>

<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1234.css">
 </head>
<body>
<h1>huy</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
 body {
     background-image: url("images/scenery.jpg");
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below snipped how to use background

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1234.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>huy</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have updated the code for you. Try using the above snippet to see how it works

Comment: i don't understand what you have done there but when i copy/paste the code.....it doesn't show the background....i am using sublime text

Comment: One quick question, why does he need bootstrap?

Comment: @ShoaibMirza Use "Run Code Snippet " button here, and you could see background-image getting applied.

Comment: @ShoaibMirza No you don't need bootstrap. That was my miss. Deleted it now.

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari yeah its working here,but why not in my browser.

Comment: @ShoaibMirza Is your background image is available at the path you have mentioned? If you have idea about Inspector Tools, try using that and see your background image is getting picked?

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari   i have tried adding image in my html code with same source,and it worked.

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari i was talking about the path. it work when i try to add image directly,but background image is not working with the same path.

Comment: @ShoaibMirza Can you share your CSS file/HTML file/ and image path structure in a directory?

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari ok, it worked,i was writing (image/sceney.jpg) and it should have been(../image/scenery.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

The html and body may need to be set "height: 100%"

Try adding these code in your css:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```